# How to access models in default module in Zend_Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

I'm trying to make my application modular using modules in Zend Framework.

Here is my new project structure:

> > ```
> >    configs/ 
> >         application.ini
> >     layouts/
> >         filters/
> >         helpers/
> >         scripts/
> >     modules/
> >         default/
> >                forms/
> >                controllers/
> >                models/
> >                views/
> >         admin/
> >                forms/
> >                controllers/
> >                models/
> >                views/
> >     Bootstrap.php
> > ```

I've added these lines in my application .ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = false
resources.modules[] =
```

I can now access the controllers and views in the default directory without changing anything in my previous configuration (I just moved my controllers/models/views into the module/ directory).

However, I can't access to models located in the default module.

Here is the error displayed when I tried to access to this model from a controller:

> Fatal error: Class 'Model_Account_Edit' not found in /var/www/.../application/modules/default/controllers/AccountController.php on line 138

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you're missing a module specific bootstrap.
Add a bootstrap file to each module and it should work. The class should look something like this:

```
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap{}
```

Add it to the project

```
modules/
    default/
           forms/
           controllers/
           models/
           views/
           Bootstrap.php
```

And you should be ready to go.